# help me please proof about contiunity of metric

Tags: metric-spaces

metric is a continuous function.I need to prove that.But I cannot show that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|d(x,y)-d(y,a)| < \varepsilon $.  for any metric $d$

$|x-a|<\delta$ is it true? or Should I that $d(x,a)<\delta$. I am confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ be your metric space. $d:E\times E \to \mathbb R_+$ its distance.

Saying that $d$ is continuous at $X\in E\times E$ is saying that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \alpha >0, \forall Y \in E\times E, D(X,Y)\le \alpha \implies |d(X)-d(Y)|\le \varepsilon$

The problem here is that you didn't give $D$, the metric on $E\times E$. You can define it using $d$ but there are several ways to do so and some might not make $d$ continuous. Your statement is true for $D((x,y),(a,b))=\max\{d(x,a),d(y,b)\}$.

$$\begin{array}{ll}
|d(x,y)-d(a,b)| &= |d(x,y)-d(x,b)+d(x,b)-d(a,b)|\\
&\le |d(x,y)-d(x,b)|+|d(x,b)-d(a,b)|\\
&\le d(y,b)+d(x,a)\\
&\le 2\max\{d(x,a),d(y,b)\}\\
|d(x,y)-d(a,b)| &\le 2 D((x,y),(a,b))
\end{array}$$

So you can take $\alpha = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Comment: is that true? because we need to prove for any metric

Comment: You need not consider $E\times E$ as metric space, onl yas topological space, endowed with the product topology. Of course the topology on $E$ is the one given by the metric $d$.

Comment: Well this metric induces the product topology anyway.

Comment: Thanks.allright is it uniformly contiounus?

Comment: Yes, since the $\alpha$ doesn't depend on $X$. Another way to see it: My last inequality says that it is Lipschitz continuous which implies uniformly continuous.